# net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error when doing a request to a nodejs page

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, url-rewriting, web-config

Hi I have write a rule to be processed by nodejs server.js page.
This is the web.config file

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
         <match url="(.*)" /> 
         <conditions> 
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
         </conditions> 
         <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
       </rule>

       <rule name="NodeJs Server Page Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="server/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="server/server.js" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is my http request using ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(db),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../server/uploads',                       
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          if(data == "Success")
            window.location.href="profile.html";
          else
            errors(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {    
          errors(err);
        }
      });
```

This is the structure of my folders
[image]

Inside server folder is my server.js file.

This is error I am getting

> jquery.min.js:2 GET
>   https://facestylist.azurewebsites.net/server/server.js
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Pretty sure that the `<match url="server/" />` will match any url with `server/` within, ie `/server/server.js` will match - so it will attempt to redirect to `/server/server.js` but the rule will kick-in to say redirect.  You could try updating your rule, eg to `<match url="server/$" />`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-pattern-syntax

Comment: hi now i am getting 404 error

Comment: Does it work if you remove the rule completely?

Comment: yes, but i need to call the nodejs file when the http done

Comment: The `NodeJs Server Page Redirect` is saying 'when I see "server/" redirect to "server/server.js"' - if you explicitly set the correct nodejs file to "server/server.js" (which you do) rather than just "server/" then you shouldn't even need that rule.

Comment: still getting the 404 error